# Error starting docker containers

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am trying to start docker containers using a script, however, I have observed that the containers do not start at random, and I get the similar error message every time -

```
level="fatal" msg="Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 5cdfbcf5bcf140410e8bec0055614f2d93afaa04fd455e9a7960fed546cf0fa3: Error getting container 5cdfbcf5bcf140410e8bec0055614f2d93afaa04fd455e9a7960fed546cf0fa3 from driver devicemapper: Error mounting '/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-275538-5cdfbcf5bcf140410e8bec0055614f2d93afaa04fd455e9a7960fed546cf0fa3' on '/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/5cdfbcf5bcf140410e8bec0055614f2d93afaa04fd455e9a7960fed546cf0fa3': no such file or directory"
```

However, if i run the same command again after it fails, it works.

I am launching the containers using Weave.

Can anyone tell me how to prevent this from happening, or a shell script which checks if the error is thrown and automatically run it again?

Comment: can you be more specific, what is this command that fails once then next time works fine! Can you post your script.

Comment: Looks like this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker building fails randomly with Error mounting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072532/docker-building-fails-randomly-with-error-mounting)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6675

What shows

`docker version`

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug occuring with `devicemapper` driver only.

Here is the reference of the bug: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4036

Best solution is to switch either to `aufs` or `overlayfs` drivers.

Note that this question seems to be a duplicate from this one: [Docker building fails randomly with Error mounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072532)